# ggplot2 sorting a plot Part II

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a melted data.frame, dput(x), below:

```
## dput(x)    
x <- structure(list(variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), class = "factor"), 
value = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("Never Heard of", 
"Heard of but Not at all Familiar", 
"Somewhat Familiar", "Familiar", "Very Familiar", "Extremely Familiar"
), class = "factor"), freq = c(10L, 24L, 32L, 90L, 97L, 69L, 
15L, 57L, 79L, 94L, 58L, 19L, 11L, 17L, 34L, 81L, 94L, 85L, 4L, 
28L, 59L, 114L, 82L, 35L)), .Names = c("variable", "value", "freq"
), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")
```

Which looks like this (for those of you who don't need a test set):

```
   variable                            value freq
1         a                   Never Heard of   10
2         a Heard of but Not at all Familiar   24
3         a                Somewhat Familiar   32
4         a                         Familiar   90
5         a                    Very Familiar   97
6         a               Extremely Familiar   69
7         b                   Never Heard of   15
8         b Heard of but Not at all Familiar   57
9         b                Somewhat Familiar   79
10        b                         Familiar   94
11        b                    Very Familiar   58
12        b               Extremely Familiar   19
13        c                   Never Heard of   11
14        c Heard of but Not at all Familiar   17
15        c                Somewhat Familiar   34
16        c                         Familiar   81
17        c                    Very Familiar   94
18        c               Extremely Familiar   85
19        d                   Never Heard of    4
20        d Heard of but Not at all Familiar   28
21        d                Somewhat Familiar   59
22        d                         Familiar  114
23        d                    Very Familiar   82
24        d               Extremely Familiar   35
```

Now, I can make a nice and pretty plot akin to this:

```
ggplot(x, aes(variable, freq, fill = value)) + 
geom_bar(position = "fill") + 
coord_flip() + 
scale_y_continuous("", formatter="percent")
```

### Question

What I would like to do is sort a,b,c,d by the highest to lowest "freq" of "Extremely Familiar"

`?relevel` and `?reorder` haven't provided any constructive examples for this usage.

Your help, is always appreciated.

Cheers,

BEB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
tmpfun <- function(i) {
    tmp <- x[i,]
    -tmp[ tmp$value=='Extremely Familiar', 'freq' ]
}

x$variable <- reorder( x$variable, 1:nrow(x), tmpfun )
```

Comment: It's so close! Is there a way to reverse this ordering? (Adding a minus sign somewhere?) When I use coord_flip() it sorts it in the opposite direction.

Comment: To reverse the ordering remove the minus sign in the definition of tmpfun.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way to do it:

```
tmp <- subset(x, value=="Extremely Familiar")
x$variable <- factor(x$variable, levels=levels(x$variable)[order(-tmp$freq)])
```