# How to order breaks with ggplot / geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data.frame with entries like:

```
   variable  importance order
1       foo  0.06977263     1
2       bar  0.05532474     2
3       baz  0.03589902     3
4     alpha  0.03552195     4
5      beta  0.03489081     5
       ...
```

When plotting the above, with the breaks = variable, I would like for the order to be preserved, rather than placed in alphabetical order.

I am rendering with:

```
 
ggplot (data, aes(x=variable, weight=importance, fill=variable)) + 
    geom_bar() + 
    coord_flip() + opts(legend.position='none')
```

However, the ordering of the variable names is alphabetical, and not the order within the data frame.  I had seen a post about using "order" in aes, but appears to have no effect.

I am looking to have a breaks ordering in-line with the "order" column.

There seems to be a similar question [How to change the order of discrete x scale in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253641/how-to-change-the-order-of-a-discrete-x-scale-in-ggplot), but frankly, did not understand the answer in this context.

Comment: FYI: It's easier for people to answer if you use `dput` and add a small sample of the data to the end of your post (or else use a globally available dataset from the `datasets` package in base R).

Comment: Is `variable` a character or a factor?

Comment: variable is a factor.  I'm going to look at the answers below ...

Comment: Shane, thanks for the tip.  Was not aware of dput.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
data$variable <- factor(data$variable, levels=levels(data$variable)[order(-data$order)])
```

From: [ggplot2 sorting a plot Part II](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791039/ggplot2-sorting-a-plot-part-ii)

Answer (score 4):

Even shorter and easier to understand:

```
data$Variable <- reorder(data$Variable, data$order)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to plot the order and then change the labels after the fact:

```
df <- data.frame(variable=letters[c(3,3,2,5,1)], importance=rnorm(5), order=1:5)
p <- qplot(x=order, weight=importance, fill=variable, data=df, geom="bar") + 
  scale_x_continuous("", breaks=1:5, labels=df$variable) + 
  coord_flip() + opts(legend.position='none')
```

Comment: Thanks.  This solves it. Wish there was a built-in approach with an order attribute, but I suppose would not be a widely used feature.

Answer (score 1):

A shot in the dark, but maybe something like this:

```
data$variable <- factor(data$variable, levels=data$variable)
```